# Virtual Box Doesn't work after running the docker desktop app

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-desktop

hope all of you are doing fine. I have a slightly weird problem which I can't track to get along with I have virtual box and docker desktop both installed on my ubuntu desktop linux machine installed and every time which I run the docker desktop app on my machine
the virtual box shows the below error

> A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.

I rebooted the system and started the virtual box and everything was Ok
and to ensure that the problem was caused by the conflict between docker desktop vm
and virutal box
I ran the docker desktop and went to virtual box
and faced the same error again
I kinda think that there is a kind of conflict between virtualization systems of docker and virtual box as I see
but I don't understand in detail that what the problem could be
I am fairly new to docker and virtualization and I don't have any deep knowledge about the subject
thank you so much

Comment: Docker Desktop wants to run Docker inside a Linux VM, which isn't really necessary on a native-Linux host.  Can you uninstall the Desktop application and use Docker directly through its CLI?

Comment: thank you David I want to know what is the underlaying problem

Comment: You're trying to start a VM from inside another VM.  This usually doesn't work.